# What will this bright green caterpillar with small turquoise spots turn into?

Tags: bugs, bug-identification, caterpillars, romania

We found this beauty in our yard:

[image]

It was 10 cm long and it was crawling pretty fast. What made it even more spectacular were the little turquoise spots on it. I suppose it will be a butterfly (but correct me if I'm wrong). Does anyone have a clue what species it is? I tried to look at some moth/caterpillar identification webpages, but with no success (they are covering mostly the United States).

We live in [Cluj county, Romania](https://www.google.ro/maps/place/Cluj+County/@46.88202,22.8685,148210m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x47490c1f916c0b8b:0x42469dc74237d9e8!8m2!3d46.7941797!4d23.6121492?hl=en) (moderate continental climate).

Comment: What a wonderful specimen!  I wish your finger, toe, or boot was nearby to get a better feel of how big these can be!

Comment: RockPaperLz- Mask it or Casket it was around 8-10 cm big

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's the [Great Peacock Moth Caterpillar](https://www.whatsthatbug.com/2011/07/22/great-peacock-moth-caterpillar-from-greece/).

See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturnia_pyri) for other images, including a painting of the moth by Van Gogh.

> Saturnia pyri, the giant peacock moth, also called the great peacock
>   moth, giant emperor moth, or Viennese emperor, is a Saturniid moth
>   which is native to Europe. It is the largest European moth, with a
>   wingspan reaching 15-20 cm.
>
> In French it is called Grand paon de nuit.

The picture on the left is from [Caterpillars, Romania](https://www.google.com/search?q=Caterpillars,+Romania&tbm=isch&imgil=w3__kTeS8gn4dM%253A%253BSliZUM-KvIShBM%253Bhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.whatsthatbug.com%25252F2011%25252F07%25252F04%25252Fgreat-peacock-moth-caterpillar-from-france-2%25252F&source=iu&pf=m&fir=w3__kTeS8gn4dM%253A%252CSliZUM-KvIShBM%252C_&usg=__bvfSdnLkglURmB-M8pBM5NvhleI%3D&biw=1261&bih=615&ved=0ahUKEwjW5Neuq5fVAhVBNiYKHT7sCmYQyjcIOQ&ei=3ltwWdb9NsHsmAG-2KuwBg#imgdii=frd-Yqtty_JhSM:&imgrc=w3__kTeS8gn4dM:&spf=1500535777223).
The picture on the right shows the caterpillar and the moth. It's from [Worldwide Butterflies](http://www.wwb.co.uk/giant-peacock-moth-pyri-5-cocoons).

[image]
[image]

There's an excellent picture of the entire lifecyle of the moth [here](http://www.alamy.com/stock-photo-complete-life-cycle-of-giant-peacock-moth-saturnia-pyri-caterpillars-52277887.html). It shows the cocoons and moths in various stages while they change color and shape as they mature. There's a charge to download it, so I didn't do that, but I highly recommend checking it out.